# Taking array as an input to function in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell and I stumbled upon a problem in my Haskell code. I have a function,

```
main = print (qSort [distance (3,4), distance (1,2), distance (2,2)])

distance :: (Floating a ) => (a,a) -> (a,a,a)
distance (x2 , y2) = (x2*x2 + y2*y2, x2, y2)
```

that calculates distance between (0,0) and given point. How can change it to something like:

```
    main = print (qSort (distance [(3,4),(1,2),(2,2)]))
```

so that *distance* can take a whole array as input?
Also, what way will be the best to try and get the points as input from the user? Looking at examples I can't really think of a way to get points.
I've tried fiddling with square brackets, but I keep getting errors. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting `map distance` instead of `distance` in the second code.

But you have to lookup and understand [what `map` does](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map)!

In this case, `map` is telling `distance` *Hey, man, you're promoted! Yeah, you don't just work on loosers pairs, `(a,a)`; you work on lists of them, `[(a,a)]`, all at once!*

(The technical term for *promoted* is *lifted*, btw.)

If you're really at the start, I suggest that you go though some tutorial/book. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) is a very good place to start.